# Color Printing in Luang Prabang

Tags: laos

Does anyone know of a shop or internet cafe with color printing capabilities in Luang Prabang?

Or is it available pretty easily in most places?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [hobomap of Luang Prabang](http://hobomaps.com/LuangPrabangCentralMap.html), mentioning two copy shops:

> copy shop : FP122, FU126
> stationery & copy shop : FP122

The Laos Yellow pages also mention two [photocopy equipment shops](http://laoyp.com/categories/la12440-photocopying-equipment-services/listings) in Luang Prabang:

> 7. [ACE Equipment (Luangprabang Branch)](http://laoyp.com/listings/la101997-ace-equipment-luangprabang-branch)
>
> [...]
>
> 16. [Siliphone Photocopy Shop](http://laoyp.com/listings/la112436-siliphone-photocopy-shop)

Note that the first one seems to be more of a shop selling photocopiers and printers.

Now whether any of these offer colour printing is something to be verified in person.